# dev/kvm is not found issue / enable VT-x in bios

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

Today i installed emulator and HAXM update from Android Studio SDK manager. After that i can not start my emulator.

Please note -

- I had my emulator working before.
- I have enable VT-x tech in bios.
- I have disabled security boot.
- and tried all answers which i found.

[image]

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research on this. Finally i solved it out.

Even i have enable VT-X tech and disabled secure boot. My Android Studio failed to load emulator saying `dev/kvm not found`.

This issue came after updating HAXM. I found some useful answers. which tell this issue is in HAXM 7.2.0. See [this issue on github](https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/56)

Steps to solve:

- Uninstall Haxm from SDK manager.
- downloaded previous version of HAXM v7.1.0 from [this release page](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases).
- Install this HAXM.

Now everything should work fine as before.